# What do these instructions mean?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

In the last two months, I learned basic reverse engineering, assembly, and C. I got a binary from my friend; they asked me to reverse that binary to original source. I used IDA Pro to reverse the binary file, but I have some problem with these instructions below:

```
mov     [esp+230h+var_218], 74654D5Fh
mov     [esp+230h+var_214], 754D6C61h
mov     [esp+230h+var_210], 6873696Ch
mov     [esp+230h+var_20C], 5F61h
```

I'm try to search the hex but I didn't find any results. Can someone explain?

Comment: Looks like "Hello world", or some variant thereof. Try reading it as ASCII.

Comment: thanks for comment,, I have found what does it mean.. thanks

Comment: *reverse that binary to original source.*  Impossible.  You can't recover the comments at all, and without debug symbols, not even the original variable names.  The best you can do is basically re-writing the original source with your own comments and meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

x86 is little endianness, so in order to read it you start from right to left of the dword literal.

The string is "*_MetalMulisha_*", fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on [Lord Kale XI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630174/1354557), x86 is a [little endian archiecture](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html).  This effectively means that we store the bytes of multi-byte integers *backwards*, that is, with the least significant byte first.  The link I provided gives a pretty good explanation of how this works.

So in these instructions, we first move the integer `74654D5Fh` to somewhere in memory.  In order, this actually writes the bytes `5F 4D 65 74`.  Then, we write the integer `754D6C61h` to the *next* four bytes in memory, which writes `61 6C 4D 75`, and so on.

After these instructions, the memory contains the following sequence of bytes, each of which can be interpreted as an ASCII character:

```
  0x74654D5F      0x754D6C61      0x6873696C      0x00005F61
       |               |               |               |
       V               V               V               V
[   var_218  ]  [   var_214  ]  [   var_210  ]  [   var_20C  ]
5F  4D  65  74  61  6C  4D  75  6C  69  73  68  61  5F  00  00
'_' 'M' 'e' 't' 'a' 'l' 'M' 'u' 'l' 'i' 's' 'h' 'a' '_' '\0' '\0'
```

So then, what these instructions are doing is writing the null-terminated string `_MetalMulisha_` to memory starting at `var_218`.